# Why can JValue be implicitly converted to MonadicJValue even if jvalue2monadic is not imported?

Tags: scala, json4s

In json4s, code can be written like this:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
...
val x: MonadicJValue = JObject()
```

This is correct because the function

```
implicit def jvalue2monadic(jv: JValue) = new MonadicJValue(jv)
```

is imported to the scope by the first `import org.json4s._` line.

[(source of jvalue2monadic defination on github)](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/v3.2.11/core/src/main/scala/org/json4s/package.scala)

However, I tried another segment of codes and it works well too:

```
import org.json4s.{JObject, MonadicJValue}
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.parse
...
val x: MonadicJValue = JObject()
```

Since the implicit function is not imported to this scope, I don't know how it works!

Comment: I believe it's because JObject and the implicit are defined in the same object, but I'm not certain

Comment: @Daenyth I tried a little demo myself, defining my class and the implicit function just like what json4s does, but it turns out that my implicit doesn't work at all. So I don't think it's because they are defined in the same object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got the answer from the post [Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits)

> From the book *"Programming in Scala, 2nd Edition"* which is based on Scala 2.8, I learned the implicit rules that **the scala compiler will look for implicit definitions in the companion object of the source or target types**, however I didn't learn that **the scala compiler will also look for implicit definitions in the outer object for nested types**.

In the question above, the implicit definition

`implicit def jvalue2monadic(jv: JValue) = new MonadicJValue(jv)`

is defined in the package object `org.json4s`, which is the outer object in the package hierachy nesting either `JValue`/`JObject` or `MonadicJValue`. So, `jvalue2monadic` will surely be used by the scala compiler when needed.